# Google Play - onReceivedSslError

Tags: java, android, google-play, jakarta-mail, backendless

I have read all themes about this, but didnt find the answer...

Google Play has sent me this.

> In your application detected unsafe implementation
>   WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError handler. .... The list of
>   applications and classes, subject to change, sent to the email address
>   that you specified during the registration of the developer.

Firstly, i havent recieved any email from it. So i dont know which classes i should change. BUT, the main thing, that i have searched "onReceivedSslError" in my classes, and i didnt find this method... So i dont use it.

However, i use gmailSending and its api JavaMail. Also one library jar for cloud connection. Thats all where i am using Internet connection. Please, tell me, where i am wrong. What should i do ? Maybe the libraries cause that problem ?
Also, i tried to use command prompt in Android Studio . I typed tis

```
find . -name '*.jar' -exec zipgrep -i onreceivedsslerror {} \;
```

but the command prompt says that it didnt find '*.jar'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webview avoid security alert from google play upon implementation of onReceivedSslError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050741/webview-avoid-security-alert-from-google-play-upon-implementation-of-onreceiveds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest version of Backendless Android SDK, you can download jar directly from Backendless: https://github.com/Backendless/Android-SDK/blob/master/out/backendless.jar?raw=true

Or wait some time until it will appear on Maven repository.

Also, you can look at the discussion on this at Backendless Support Forum: http://support.backendless.com/topic/app-has-received-warning-about-onreceivedsslerror