# Reoccurred. Webview avoid security alert from google play upon implementation of onReceivedSslError

Tags: android-security, sslerrorhandler

[Webview avoid security alert from google play upon implementation of onReceivedSslError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050741/webview-avoid-security-alert-from-google-play-upon-implementation-of-onreceiveds)

We have done the steps written in the above link.
And we have confirmed that the alert was removed on March.

But on April 22nd, we got the same alert from Google Play.
We have confirmed that our APK is still showing the SSL alert correctly on the device.
Has Google changed their policy?

Comment: What is the app name?

Comment: Sorry I can't tell the app name, because the project is from our client.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry we've found out that our APK had another webview, which we are not currently using.
And that did not have the SSL alert, so that was the problem.