# Android playstore warning "your application has unsafe implementation of WebViewClient.onReceivedError handler"

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payment

I have released app into market , after a week we have received  this error.
I want to know
1)Will the app get blocked soon
2)How to solve this problem

Comment: you have removed onReceivedSslError method! Check all library and update code

Comment: I have this implementation which is unsafe as per warning that i have received
@Override
      public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
      }

Comment: you can refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050741/webview-avoid-security-alert-from-google-play-upon-implementation-of-onreceiveds/36147896#36147896)