# Your APK has been rejected for containing security vulnerabilities, which violates the Malicious Behavior policy

Tags: android, google-play

I submit app on Google Play Store

I received information from Google:

**Your APK has been rejected for containing security vulnerabilities, which violates the Malicious Behavior policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play.**

My app is a communication app, It use Linphone Android for video call, use Java socket for chat, use Twilio for Call Phone, webservice

Library used:

- org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2
- jackson-annotations-2.6.0-rc3.jar
- jackson-databind-2.6.0-rc3.jar
- jackson-core-2.6.0-rc3.jar
- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
- com.android.support:design:23.1.1
- gcm.jar
- aXMLRPC_v1.7.2.jar
- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+
- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0
- twilioclient-android.jar
- universal-image-loader-1.6.1-with-src.jar

Who can help me solution???

Comment: you dont leave anyone an app name, any source code. or anything to go off of. if you post anything many of us will be happy to help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050741/webview-avoid-security-alert-from-google-play-upon-implementation-of-onreceiveds

Comment: Oh sorry, it will be update