# Google Play Warning Vulnerability SSL Error Handler

Tags: ssl, handler

I do not know where the problem is.
I would appreciate your attention. It is a starter.

Your app uses software that contains elements that make your security less secure, or software that allows you to collect user data without proper notice.

Below is a list of errors found in recently submitted apps and their APK versions. Please update your app as soon as possible and increase your updated APK version number.

Vulnerability APK version
SSL Error Handler

For more information on how to address WebView SSL Error Handler alerts, please see this Google Help Center article.
7

To ensure that your update is working properly, submit an updated version of your app to the Developer Console and double check that the warning has disappeared after 5 hours.

While vulnerabilities do not affect all apps that use this software, it is best to keep all security patches current. If you're not sure if this is a problem with your app, please update all of your app's known known

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadApplication("moml/applicationInfo.xml");}
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="k2communication.k2communication" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />    // 인터넷 관련 퍼미션
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="앤텔레콤-선불요금제"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="앤텔레콤-선불요금제"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: And what was at "this Google Help Center article"?

Comment: Your question does not provide enough information to really determine what the problem is but my guess is that you essentially have the same problem as described in [Webview avoid security alert from google play upon implementation of onReceivedSslError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050741/) and thus I marked it as duplicate. If you feel that this is not a duplicate please add enough details to your question so that it gets clear that it is not a duplicate of any existing question and enough details to actually help you with the problem.

Comment: - Security Notification -

Your app is using an unsafe implementation of the WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError handler. Please visit the Google Customer Center Help for more details, such as the time of the vulnerability resolution.

Vulnerable class:


Org.mospi.moml.framework.pub.ui.MOMLWebViewClient



Affects version 7 of the APK.

Comment: @ Philip Kendall  앱의 WebView SSL 오류 핸들러 알림 해결 방법


이 도움말은 앱에서 WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError 핸들러를 안전하지 않은 방식으로 구현한 개발자를 위한 정보입니다. 특히 해당 구현은 모든 SSL 인증서 확인 오류를 무시하기 때문에 앱이 중간자 공격에 취약해집니다. 공격자는 영향을 받은 WebView의 콘텐츠를 변경하고 전송된 데이터(예: 로그인 사용자 인증 정보)를 읽고 자바스크립트를 사용해 앱 내부에서 코드를 실행할 수 있습니다.  

2016년 11월 25일부터 Google Play에서 이 취약성을 포함하는 새로운 앱 또는 업데이트의 게시를 차단합니다. 게시된 APK 버전은 영향을 받지 않지만 이 취약점을 해결하기 전까지는 모든 앱 업데이트가 차단됩니다.


SSL 오류 핸들러에 대한 자세한 정보는 Android 개발자 고객센터의 문서를 참조하시기 바랍니다. 다른 기술 관련 질문은 https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions에 'android-security' 및 'SslErrorHandler' 태그를 추가하여 게시하세요.