# Cordova Google WebView SSL Error Handler alerts

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ssl, webview

I developed an App using the Ionic Platform and Cordova. After I submitted it to Google Playstore, I received and email about "**security vulnerabilities**".

> This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.

[Here's how they wanted to address WebView SSL Error Handler alerts.](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7071387)

I tried using AlertDialog.Builder as what [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050741/webview-avoid-security-alert-from-google-play-upon-implementation-of-onreceiveds?answertab=active#tab-top) fixed the issue.

I copied the code to SystemWebviewClient.java

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
...
```

But it's not accepting "***this***" as context parameter.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the Context from the parent engine of the SystemWebviewClient by this.parentEngine.getView().getContext().

It worked for me but my app still gets rejected from Google Play Console.