# SSL seurity err in webview

Tags: android, ssl, webview, google-play-console-beta

Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please migrate your apps to use the updated software as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

SSL Error Handler
For more information on how to address WebView SSL Error Handler alerts, please see this Google Help Center article.

Lcom/prvaas/prvaas/MainActivity$1;
Lcom/prvaas/prvaas/MainActivity$1;

this msg I got from play store. while SSl code part is there .

anyone can help....

Comment: show your SSL implementation

Comment: mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @SuppressLint("WebViewClientOnReceivedSslError")
            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed();
            }
        });

Comment: and in folder I have added SSL Cerificate. cert file

Answer (score 1):

you are getting `onReceivedSslError` call, but inside this method you are calling `handler.proceed();` means that `WebView` detected some inconsistency and you are calling `proceed` anyway allowing to load data/site. this isn't SSL handling, this is disabling SSL at all allowing ANY certificate to be proceeded even with error/not valid

your code also contains `@SuppressLint("WebViewClientOnReceivedSslError")`, which prevents Android Studio to show you a warning that this isn't secure way... remove this line and read lint warning

related topic in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050741/webview-avoid-security-alert-from-google-play-upon-implementation-of-onreceiveds)