# WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError on published flutter android app bundle

Tags: flutter, android-security, android-app-bundle

We have deveoloped an Flutter application. We use the following package 'webview_flutter' for WebView display in flutter application. Application works fine with android. We published an app bundle in play store from developer console.

Then we got a 'Security vulnerabilities' error as shown below. There is no clue to fix this issue.

```
onReceivedSslError
error
Error
brightness_1
Security
Your app is using an unsafe implementation of WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError handler. Please see this Google Help Centre article for details, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.

io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.FlutterWebView$FlutterWebChromeClient$1
sv:deadline:03/13/2023
```

After google for sometime, I found the solution in stackoverflow for the android version of program here [Android Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050741/webview-how-to-avoid-security-alert-from-google-play-upon-implementation-of-onr)

Any suggestions for the solution in Flutter programming would be appriciated.

Comment: Upgradin to th latest version of webview_flutter solves this problem. As the latest version does not have the WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError callback in it.